# databricks-connect failed to connect to Databricks cluster runtime 8.4

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I have the following setup

Databricks Cluster:

```
8.4 ML (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12)
```

Client side:

```
databricks==0.2
databricks-cli==0.14.3
databricks-connect==8.1.10 (The latest version up to date 20210813)
```

When I run `databricks-connect test` to test the connection, I got this error message

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
The cluster is running server version `dbr-8.4` but this client only supports Set(dbr-8.1). 
You can find a list of client releases at https://pypi.org/project/databricks-connect/#history, and install the right client version with `pip install -U databricks-connect==<version>`. 
For example, to install the latest 5.1 release, use `pip install -U databricks-connect==5.1.*`. 
To ignore this error and continue, set DEBUG_IGNORE_VERSION_MISMATCH=1.
```

According to the error message, I understand there is a compatibility issue with the client and server versions. However, I am already using the latest client.

1. Does it mean the client doesn't add support for server version 8.4?
2. Is there any way to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's the latest version of databricks-connect for DBR 8.x., and versions for 8.2-8.4 aren't released.  But it **may** work if you add `DEBUG_IGNORE_VERSION_MISMATCH=1` before the `databricks-connect test` or other commands like, `pyspark`, `spark-submit`, etc.